# Scraping - Drop menu to select the number of items to show

Tags: python-3.x, drop-down-menu, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a site that has a drop down menu where the user can select the number of items it displays.

Even if I select the option to see all results, when I parse the page's URL using  bs4 I obtain only the results for the elements displayed on the default page.

This is the URL: http://www.archivioelettorale.it/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=36:elezioni-comunali&Itemid=58

This is my (still rudimental) code:

```
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36'}
site = "http://www.archivioelettorale.it/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=36:elezioni-comunali"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(site,headers=headers,timeout=5).text, 'html.parser')

list_1 = []
list_2 = []
elections_anchors = soup.find_all(class_=re.compile('sectiontableentry'))
for extract in elections_anchors:
    list_1.extend(extract.select('a'))

for element in list_1:
list_2.append('http://www.archivioelettorale.it' + element['href'])
```

The drop down menu is the one saying: "Mostra #"
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the form data if you inspect the network traffic when you click the drop-down menu. Then submit the form data with a POST request.

```
data = {
    'filter':'', 'limit':0, 'id':36, 'sectionid':5, 
    'task':'category', 'filter_order':'', 'filter_order_Dir':'', 
    'limitstart':0, 'viewcache':0
    }
headers = {
    'user-agent': 
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36'
    }
site = "http://www.archivioelettorale.it/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=36:elezioni-comunali"
r = requests.post(site, data=data, headers=headers, timeout=20)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

The page takes some time to load, so i increased the timeout. You should now have 4888 results.